# Calculate which way to turn a boid to get to an object in Java

Tags: java, angle, boids

**tl;dr**: I have angle x and angle y in radians; Which way do I need to turn angle x to match angle y?

I have a [boid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boids) with an `angle` which desires to point towards a `goalAngle` (angles are in radians). However the boid cannot turn at a speed greater than defined in `Constants.maxTurningSpeed` (multiplied by `timePassed` - how long it has been since the last physics update). If this speed is exceeded then it should instead turn at the maximum speed in that direction. The only issue is *which direction*.

The following code works for most scenarios but can break when going over the 0 threshold. Any help?

```java
if ((this.goalAngle - this.angle) % (2*Math.PI) > (Constants.maxTurningSpeed*timePassed)) { // turn left or right?
    this.angle += Constants.maxTurningSpeed*timePassed;
} else if ((this.goalAngle - this.angle) % (2*Math.PI) < -(Constants.maxTurningSpeed*timePassed)) {
    this.angle -= Constants.maxTurningSpeed*timePassed;
} else {
    this.angle = this.goalAngle;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution online in this [blog post](http://www.paulboxley.com/blog/2012/05/angles) by Paul Bloxel. This better describes the issue and solution.